# Javascript cumulate an array of object to an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "date" : "03/01/2017",
        "value" : 2
    },  {
        "date" : "04/01/2017",
        "value" : 6
    },  {
        "date" : "05/01/2017",
        "value" : 4
    }
];
```

I need to cumulate the value and keep the same array with updated values

The result would look like this

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "date" : "03/01/2017",
        "value" : 2
    },  {
        "date" : "04/01/2017",
        "value" : 8 //(2+6)
    },  {
        "date" : "05/01/2017",
        "value" : 12 //(2+6+4)
    }
];
```

I am aware that this exists

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});
```

But I cannot find an example with object returning also objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *this* argument of `Array.prototype.forEach` to accumulated the *value* - see demo below:

```js
var myArray=[{"date":"03/01/2017","value":2},{"date":"04/01/2017","value":6},{"date":"05/01/2017","value":4}];

myArray.forEach(function(e){
  this.count = (this.count || 0) +  e.value;
  e.value = this.count;
},Object.create(null));

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: Why not just `{}` instead of `Object.create(null)` ? Nice approach anyway

Comment: `{}` includes the inherited prototypes too... `Object.create(null)` will avoid them...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` and `Object.assign()` to make copy of objects.

```js
var myArray = [{
  "date": "03/01/2017",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "date": "04/01/2017",
  "value": 6
}, {
  "date": "05/01/2017",
  "value": 4
}];

var result = myArray.map(function(o) {
  var obj = Object.assign({}, o)
  obj.value = this.total += o.value
  return obj
}, {total: 0})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as a different example and to answer your question on `.reduce()`, you'd use reduce in this way

```js
var myArray = [
    {
        "date" : "03/01/2017",
        "value" : 2
    },  {
        "date" : "04/01/2017",
        "value" : 6
    },  {
        "date" : "05/01/2017",
        "value" : 4
    }
];

function accumulate() {
  var count = 0;
  return myArray.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    count += cur.value || 0;
    cur.value = count;
    acc.push(cur);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(accumulate(myArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `forEach` that mutates the array in place.

```js
var myArray = [
    {
        "date" : "03/01/2017",
        "value" : 2
    },  
    {
        "date" : "04/01/2017",
        "value" : 6
    },  
    {
        "date" : "05/01/2017",
        "value" : 4
    }
];

myArray.forEach(
  (e,i,arr) => e.value += i && arr[i-1].value // only fires if i is truthy (i>0)
);      

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```